# How to send data to server using Plupload.js?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, plupload

Now, I am using plupload with my ASP Net MVC application. I'm stuck on sending data to the server (my Controller),
the code as follows:
Thank you for your help;

```
 var blob = "";
        var fileObject = new File([blob], fileName, {
            type: 'video/mp4'
        });
 var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
            runtimes: 'html5,html4',
            url: "/videoUploadHandler.ashx",
            chunk_size: '5mb',
            multi_selection: true,
            unique_names: false,
            filters: {
                mime_types: [

                     { title: "video files", extensions: "avi,mp4,mov,mwm,mkv" }
                ]
            }
        });
        uploader.init();
        uploader.files.push(fileObject);
        uploader.start();
```

videoUploadHandler.ashx

```
......................

 HttpPostedFile fileUpload = Request.Files[0];
 string fileName = fileUpload.FileName;
 var path = FileUploadPhysicalPath;
 uploadedFilename = Path.GetFileName(uploadedFilename);
 string uploadFilePath = Path.Combine(path, uploadedFilename);
  Stream stream = null;
  stream = new FileStream(uploadFilePath, (chunk == 0) ? FileMode.CreateNew : FileMode.Append);
            chunkStream.CopyTo(stream, 16384);
```

Comment: What is your question exactly ? Do you have any error message ? Incorrect behaviour ?

Comment: there is no error message, my problem, I can not recover the file in my controller (videoUploadHandler.ashx) . I put a break point on the Visual studio, no results

Comment: Do you see the POST request getting fired in your browser console/developer tool ? Maybe the problem is on client side ?